# Ceiling fan with light kit won’t power on

Tags: ceiling-fan

[image]

Having trouble Hooking up a new fan. Fan came with light kit and remote control. I have two switches on the wall. One for light, one for fan control. I have two powers and a neutral coming out of the ceiling. The light kit has 3 wires with a clip, and then a red and a white. I capped one of the powers coming out of the ceiling, and hooked up the other power to the red. I tied the grounds together as well (the picture doesn’t show that though). Still doesn’t power on. Can anyone assist?

[image]

See attached. The directions aren't even correct though. It states the fan comes with a white wire with red label, mean while it's a red wire with white label.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have in your pic a white wire hanging there loose.  What is that?

Comment: Do you have a non-contact voltage tester? Is the wall switched on? Is the breaker in the panel switched on?

Comment: The white wire is actually a ground wire. It has some white paint on it. I fully grounded everything though and hooked up the fan and it still doesn't work. This picture is just showing how I have it hooked up. Both wall switches are on. Yes breaker switch is on. I tested the hot wires and both showing power.

Comment: Ok so you have two hot wires - from two switches.  One is connected, one isn't.  Are you sure you got the right wire? Can we get pics of the switch wiring?

Comment: BTW this is a good question that deserves upvoting!

Comment: Turn the breaker off and back on. I had one of these receivers stop working and cycling the breaker brought it back to life.  (My fan was wired direct w/o a wall switch.) Flipping the wall switch off and back on should do the same thing.

Comment: How did you test the hot wires?  Are you replacing an old fan or was there nothing there previously?